# How Get data Trough DNS in C# Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dns

I have a database that stores players stats.  The database isn't working with my IP, so I want to get the data from a DNS (like 1.1.1.1)

How can I make C# script to go through the DNS?

The Problem is this Azuara blocks Iranian IP and i want somehow Get a Work Around it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd24j.png)

This is my C# code in Unity:

```
 public void GetUserData(OnDataReceivedCallback onDataReceived)
    { //called when the 'Get Data' button on the data part is pressed

        if (IsLoggedIn)
        {
            //ready to send request
            StartCoroutine(sendGetDataRequest(LoggedIn_Username, LoggedIn_Password, onDataReceived)); //calls function to send get data request
        }
    }

    IEnumerator sendGetDataRequest(string username, string password, OnDataReceivedCallback onDataReceived)
    {
        string data = "ERROR";
        IEnumerator e = DCF.GetUserData(LoggedIn_Username, LoggedIn_Password); // << Send request to get the player's data string. Provides the username and password
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return e.Current;
        }
        string response = e.Current as string; // << The returned string from the request

        if (response == "Error")
        {
            //There was another error. Automatically logs player out. This error message should never appear, but is here just in case.

            LoggedIn_Username = "";
            LoggedIn_Password = "";

            Debug.Log("Error: Unknown Error. Please try again later.");
        }
        else
        {

            data = response;
        }
        if (onDataReceived != null)
            onDataReceived.Invoke(data);
    }
```

Comment: Do I understand that you want to use a specific DNS server to get around an IP restriction? That's not how it works. If your IP is blocked you will need to use a VPN that is allowed or configure the (I'll use a general term) firewall to let the traffic through. Ideally though, you will not connect directly to a database from the client application. You will proxy data access through an API for reasons of security as well as connectivity.

Comment: yes you Got my point i don't think there is  IP restriction mybe its just connection issue but for now i just want to test the DNS mybe the DNS will fix the problem.      And if it didnt help How i can Get the VPN for script working?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "*isnt Working with my ip*"? Is your application client unable to resolve the database or is the database blocking your client? As far as VPN, that is way out of scope. I mention it because it is a common way to grant remote access to resources but that's too big a topic to discuss here. If you have a network administrator you would start with that person.

Comment: I suspect the database is using a window credential and you are using a machine that doesn't support windows credentials.  You could add a credential to the database that takes a username and password instead.

Comment: @crowcoder I mean with my IPs Dataebase will not respond and i will get a TimeOut but when i use DNS (like 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8) or VPN i can connect to Database i want to somehow add dns/VPN just to the Database connection th bypass the problem